# What is the status of the Valvrave the Liberator English Dubs?

Tags: valvrave-the-liberator

Since last licensed to Aniplex of North America, there has been only one English dubbed episode of Valvrave the Liberator. What is the current situation surrounding the English dubbed production of the anime? Will the entire series be completed? What is taking so long for the series to be completed?